# Wagtail: Image upload error after upgrading to 2.2.1

Tags: python, django, wagtail

After upgrading Wagtail from 1.13.1 to 2.2.1 and Django from 1.11.4 to 2.0.3, I am unable to upload images. It happens when I upload images while editing a page, or during a batch upload via the Images entry on the sidebar. I get a 500 error in the Wagtail back end, and this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'width' cannot be null")
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/images/multiple/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'width' cannot be null")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 31, in _cache_controlled
    response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py", line 34, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/utils.py", line 145, in wrapped_view_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 20, in inner_func
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/images/views/multiple.py", line 72, in add
    image.save()
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1283, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py", line 127, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/env/admin.studentlife.umn.edu/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 76, in execute
    raise utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'width' cannot be null")
```

Comment: To narrow things down, it might help to upgrade Wagtail to 2.0.2, 2.1.3 and 2.2.1 as separate steps and see which one triggers the problem.

Comment: @gasman It appears that 2.2.1 is the problem, 2.0.2 and 2.1.3 work fine.

Comment: @gasman Possibly of note: running migrations in either of the downgraded versions triggered this error: `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration homecoming_umn_edu.0005_auto_20180825_1456 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('wagtailimages', '0021_image_file_hash')`

Comment: @gasman Upgrading to 2.2.2 seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I got the same error for the 2.8 version. Is there any solution?